# Servlet Filter: How to get all the headers from HttpServletResponse?

Tags: java, httpresponse

This is my Filter:

```
public class SimpleFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        // where is the httpResponse.getHeaderNames()?
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

}
```

I'm using Servlet **2.5**.

I can set a header, verify if some header exists in the response, but I can't get all headers. In the HttpServletRequest this method exists (`httpServletRequest.getHeaderNames()`).

So, where is the equivalent of `getHeaderNames()` in the HttpServletResponse?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of the Servlet API are you using? The method is right [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#getHeaderNames--) (with some restrictions) in 3.0.

Comment: I'm guessing you've forgot to cast `ServletResponse` to `HttpServletResponse`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, 2.5 :(. I will add this information in the question.

Comment: @LanceJava, I'm doing that, see the code. The problem is my Servlet version, 2.5.

Comment: @DownVoter, why the negative?

Comment: Just a *guess* as to why it's not available : the application container can and do add headers beyond the scope of the web app (ex : when flushing the headers, if content size is unknown, then set HTTP chunking on). Untill the response is commited (i.e. start of HTTP BODY flush), any part of the system may add headers, without other parts knowing. Therefore, accessing response  headers at any given point is "inherently" unsafe, unless you have full control of all filters before/after up to the servlet container level. Which you never *really* have

Answer (score 0):

That's really strange... it seems there's no accessor for this in the 2.5 api (see javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html))

As a workaround, you could use a filter to wrap the response in a wrapper which has a getter (making sure the wrapper filter runs before anything else).

eg

```
public class MyResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
    private Set<String> headerNames = new HashSet<String>();

    public MyResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse delegate) {
       super(delegate);
    }

    public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
        super.addHeader(name, value);
        headerNames.add(name);
    }

    public Set<String> getHeaderNames() {
        return Collections.immutableSet(headerNames);
    }
}


public class WrapperFilter implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
       chain.doFilter(request, new MyResponseWrapper(response));
    }
}
```

Then you could call `((MyResponseWrapper) response).getHeaderNames()` somewhere further down the line. I realise this is a bit hacky :)